# Can ansible get a url from an anchor on a webpage?

Tags: ansible

I want Ansible to install a `.deb` package from a url when the url changes every week (because of updates). There is an anchor to the dynamic download url on a static download page. Is there a trick to have ansible figure out the url?

E.g. on a certain page, there is a link called *"Latest version"* as so:

```
<a href="URL_TO_DOWNLOAD_DEB">Latest version</a>.
```

Can I get ansible to get `URL_TO_DOWNLOAD_DEB`?

Here is some made-up trick that hopefully illustrates what I mean. Obviously, this does not work.

```
- name: Find link to DEB package
  regex_from_url:
    url: http://some.download.page
    regex: g/<a href="([^"]+)">Latest version<\/a>./
    register: URL_TO_DOWNLOAD_DEB
- name: Install DEB package
  apt:
    deb: {{ URL_TO_DOWNLOAD_DEB }}
```

Comment: Come on folks, downvote without comment is petty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
- name: Send GET request to target
  shell: wget -O - http://some.download.page | grep '>Latest version<' | sed -n 's/.*href="\(.*\)".*/\1/p'
  register: web
  args:
      warn: False

- name: Show download link
  debug:
    msg: "{{ web.stdout }}"
```